# How do I replace an ImageView with a label at the click of a button and then return the ImageView back?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a no internet scene with an ImageView and a button, I need to replace the ImageView by a Label when the button is pressed, and after checking the internet if there is no internet, return the ImageView back.

The problem is that there is no element change in the application and the picture remains static, the Label doesn't even appear for seconds.
My code:

MainApplication.java

```
package com.streamvoice;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

import scripts.streamvoice.Scripts;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    Scripts scripts = new Scripts();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

        if (scripts.isConnection()) {
            fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("StartScene.fxml"));
        }
        else {
            fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ConnectionErrorScene.fxml"));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1000, 500);
        stage.setTitle("Stream Voice");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

ConnectionErrorScene.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="mVBox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.streamvoice.ConnectionSceneController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="mErrorImage" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../images/connectionError.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ProgressIndicator progress="0.0" />
      <Button fx:id="mTryConnectButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#tryConnect" text="try" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

ConnectionSceneController.java

```
package com.streamvoice;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import scripts.streamvoice.Scripts;

public class ConnectionSceneController {
    Scripts scripts = new Scripts();
    @FXML private Button mTryConnectButton;
    @FXML private ImageView mErrorImage;
    @FXML private ProgressIndicator mConnectionProgressIndicator; //Затычка
    @FXML private VBox mVBox;
   
    private void tryConnect() {
        Label labelLoadAnimation = new Label("testText");

        mVBox.getChildren().set(0, labelLoadAnimation);

        if (scripts.isConnection())
        {
            mVBox.getChildren().set(0, mErrorImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `scripts.isConnection()` is a lengthy operation, it is holding up the processing of JavaFX events, which means the window is not redrawn and no user input is processed until the tryConnect method completes.

Comment: Run `scripts.isConnection()` in a background thread, by implementing a `Task<Boolean>`. See the `Task` Javadocs.

Comment: @VGR, Did I understand correctly that the window will be drawn after the tryConnection method finishes, not while it is running?

Comment: @BeWorld Yes, that’s correct. As in most (if not all) UI toolkits, window painting happens on the same thread as event handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `scripts.isConnection()` is a long-running process, executing it on the FX Application Thread will prevent the window from being redrawn until it completes.

At an intuitive level, the FX Application Thread executes a loop that does something like this:

```
while the application is running:
    if there are user events to handle:
        handle user events
    if there are animations active:
        update animations
    if there are pending runnables in Platform.runLater(), execute them

    if it is time to repaint the scene:
        if there are changes to the scene:
            recompute layout and repaint scene
```

Therefore, if you execute a long-running process on the FX Application Thread (e.g. in an event handler or in a `Runnable`
passed to `Platform.runLater()`), this loop will not get to repaint the scene until that process is complete.

You need to run the long running process on a background thread. You can use the `Task` API to do this:

```
private void tryConnect() {
    Label labelLoadAnimation = new Label("testText");

    mVBox.getChildren().set(0, labelLoadAnimation);

    Task<Boolean> testConnectionTask = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return scripts.isConnection();
        }
    };

    testConnectionTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        if (testConnectionTask.getValue()) {
            mVBox.getChildren().set(0, mErrorImage);
        }
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(testConnectionTask);
    thread.start();
}
```